# I need a latex template for Springer annals of biomedical engineering

Tags: templates

Can any body provide the latex template for a journal Annals of biomedical engineering? I couldn't find it online.

Comment: If the journal do not provide one, you will need to contact them to check that they even accept LaTeX submissions and if so what class you should use

Comment: From https://www.springer.com/journal/10439/submission-guidelines: "Papers must be submitted via upload in a word processing format, preferably in Microsoft Word. Authors can submit LaTex manuscripts as is through our online submission process. Our software can accept LaTeX manuscripts, and usually formats them properly when converting them to PDF. Errors that occur in the conversion to PDF will be fixed when the paper is being prepared for publication. However, Microsoft Word files are preferred for upload."

Comment: @leandriis Yeah I checked that I was hoping if someone already have one in Latex. Thanks

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks

Comment: Did you find the latex or word template for Annals of biomedical engineering. I am not able to find it.

Comment: @Renuka Sorry for late reply.. No I couldn't find the latex template for ABME. Though, I worked with word.